# Troubleshooting in Chrome's Print Preview

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I have a report page that when you view the page there is a minimal gap between the charts and the headers:

[image: Good]

But if the user prints or print previews the page there is a HUGE gap between the some (but not all) of the elements:

[image: Print Preview Problem]

I've tried setting Chrome up to use the print media type in the Developer Tools which applies the correct styles but doesn't result in that gap.  Can anyone suggest a way to troubleshoot this?